# openCV equivalent of a PIL resize ANTIALIAS?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

In PIL the highest quality resize from what I've seen seems to be:

```
img = img.resize((n1, n2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

For openCV this seems to be the way to do it:

```
small = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
```

So my question is, is there an additional parameter needed or will this reduce the size with least quality lost?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize):

> To shrink an image, it will generally look best with CV_INTER_AREA interpolation, whereas to enlarge an image, it will generally look best with CV_INTER_CUBIC (slow) or CV_INTER_LINEAR (faster but still looks OK).

The default for resize is `CV_INTER_LINEAR`.  Change the interpolation to `CV_INTER_AREA` since you wish to shrink the image:

```
small = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

You may wish to compare the results of both interpolations for visual verification that you are getting the best quality.

Comment: I am actually going to do both shrinking and expanding an image. It has to be an exact size and if it's not, I will need to resize it up or down. So what I am getting is that CV_INTER_LINEAR is faster and the standard good for downsizing, but CV_INTER_AREA should be used for up-sizing? I need the maximum quality.

Do you know how much slower INTER_AREA is?

Comment: @alfredox INTER_AREA is the best for making the image smaller when talking about quality.  INTER_CUBIC for making the image bigger.  INTER_LINEAR seems to be the fastest.  I'd imagine you could do some performance testing to compare each interpolation--I have not done this myself.  Re-sizing can be expensive (performance-wise).

Comment: I got an error, apparently CV_INTER_AREA doesn't exist in cv2?

Comment: I don't use Python but I believe the code would be `cv2.INTER_AREA` rather than `CV_INTER_AREA`.  Are you trying that?

Comment: My bad, I should've said that I did try that, it doesn't exist in the cv2 import.

Comment: If you want to rescale without aliasing only linear or cubic interpolations would not be sufficient. You need to additionally use gaussian smoothing.